# Java missing after firefox 3.6.3 update on xp

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, jre

XP: I just updated to firefox 3.6.3 and Java is gone, apps don't run. The Java affordances are gone from Options. Do I download Java from somewhere? Can I roll back to a firefox version that was working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open firefox and select the Tools/Add-ons/Plug-ins and see if the Java plug-ins are disabled. If so, click on enable and restart firefox.

If, for some reason, the Java runtime has been corrupted, you can download the most recent version from here:

http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Alternatively, you can download [JavaRa](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javara/) a small utility that will allow you do remove any old versions of the JRE left on your PC and also download the latest version.